# MySQL Dump Restore

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

What is a good PHP script for restoring a large MySQL database from a local file that has already been uploaded to the server?

Thanks.

Comment: What format is the file?

Comment: Read up on the MySQL operation LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE; or else go to the mysql> prompt and do it by hand from there, no PHP needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's an sql file than phpmyadmin is an option or u can do it from the mysql console with the command  source